# Java + Mysql UTF8 Problem

Tags: java, mysql, xml, utf-8, insert

as the title said, I have a problem between java and mysql

The mysql DB, tables, and columns are utf8_unicode_ci.
I have an application that took some input from an xml, then compose the query...

```
public String [] saveField(String xmltag, String lang){     
  NodeList nodo = this.doc.getElementsByTagName(xmltag);
  String [] pos = new String[nodo.getLength()];     
  for (int i = 0 ; i < nodo.getLength() ; i++ ) {
     Node child = nodo.item(i);
     pos[i] =  "INSERT INTO table (id, lang, value) VALUES (" +
        child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().toString() + " , " +
        lang + " , " + 
        "'" + child.getFirstChild().getTextContent() + "'" +
        ");";       
    }   
   return pos;
}
```

this method return an array of String that contains one or more SQL insert Query... 
then

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbname", "user", "pass");
.....
Statement s; s =
this.con.createStatement ();
s.execute(query);
```

both with `s.execyte` and `s.executeUpdate` the special characters are stored as ?

so special char are not stored correctly:
`מסירות קצרות` is stored as `?????????`

`Hi!` is stored as `Hi!`

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the source XML? Is it coming from a file or is it a string from a web service, or something else? It is possible that you original reading of the xml is causing the problem.

Comment: it's a string from a webservice, i use db.parse("http://......") to get the xml contents...

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Solved, 
I forgot to add the encoding when initializing Connection:

before was:

`con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbname", "user", "pass");`

now (working):

`con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "user", "pass");`

Comment: shouldn't it be utf8? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Comment: Yes it should but I can't suggest an edit because it is only one character

Answer (score 11):

AUGH!

Okay, so, this isn't *directly* the thing you asked for, but this:

```
 pos[i] =  "INSERT INTO table (id, lang, value) VALUES (" +
    child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().toString() + " , " +
    lang + " , " + 
    "'" + child.getFirstChild().getTextContent() + "'" +
    ");";
```

Set off all my internal "DON'T DO THIS" alarms.

Do you have absolute and complete control over the incoming text?  Are you sure someone won't have an apostrophe in the incoming text, even by accident?

Instead of creating SQL text, please refactor your code so that you end up calling:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt =
    con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (id, lang, value) VALUES (?,?,?)");
// then, in a loop:
pstmt.setString(0, child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().toString());
pstmt.setString(1, lang);
pstmt.setString(2, child.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
pstmt.execute();
```

That is, let the DB escape the text. Please, unless someday you want to have a conversation like [this one](http://xkcd.com/327).  As an advantageous side effect, this approach *may* solve your problem, assuming that the string values are still correct when you read them from the XML. (As someone else mentioned, it's very possible that things are getting messed up when you read from the XML)

Comment: lol. I can understand a side comment but  awhole answer picking on the poor fellow ? -1

Comment: @DanielMartin +1, is there a way to get final query string from `pstmt` after you set all its value, I need to know that so that I can log what query was executing.

Comment: @Watt better late than never: `pstmt.toString()` will do the trick