# Unicode characters in Grails

Tags: grails, unicode

I am trying to create an application in grails, its much like a blogging application. One of the requirement is that the application must support unicode, the user must be able to enter the blog using unicode character. I have changed the database to 'utf8_unicode_ci' and when i directly enter a unicode record to database, the text is displayed in unicode. The problem is when I enter the unicode characters from application, all I get is '?????' characters. How can I modify the application so that it supports unicode characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you didn't setup your database url correctly. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275524/java-mysql-utf8-problem).

```
jdbc:mysql:///dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```