# Java MySQL Encoding issue with UTF-8

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, alpha

I have an issue inserting a pdf text into a mysql table. The error message is as follows:
" Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x9B\xBC i...' for column 'text' at row 1"

I know that this code refers to the greek letter alpha. However, I have set 'characer set' to UTF-8 for the column text but also in the mysql connection. Also, I have tried uft8mb4. However, none of it worked.

The greek letter alpha occurs in different font types. I am not sure if this matters.

Any ideas why this does not work?

I also created a pdf file myself which contained an alpha in the text. For this example, my programme runs without any errors. Although I know that the error message refers to the alpha, there seems to be an additional issue.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
After some checking, I found that some really strange symbols were created from a formula which contained the greek letter alpha. So, apparently these unknown symbols led to the error.
However, I still do not know how to exclude any unknown symbols from the text. What is the easiest way to do this?

These are the symbols:
[image: unknown symbols]

Comment: use the MySQL BLOB datatypes

Comment: and make sure you connnect with the utf8 charset.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275524/java-mysql-utf8-problem

Comment: i do not get an error anymore. however, it looks like there is no text data in this blob-type table record. I also tried to convert it using SELECT CONVERT(text USING utf8) FROM table; but there seems to be no information stored in this record. (it is a null entry)

Comment: please see my update in my original post. shouldn't the blob type take care of any kind of unknown symbols? unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: A PDF is binary data, incompatible with UTF-8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729824/how-to-insert-blob-and-clob-files-in-mysql

Comment: blob does work if these unknown symbols are removed from the pdf. i simply have to use CONVERT to get the text information. but then i can basically use longtext as well. this is however not my problem anyways! it rather is how i automatically can remove unknown symbols from a string (either in java or mysql). see above in the update.

Answer (score 0):

I restricted the string in Java to only latin symbols. maybe that's not the most general way of getting rid of those strange symbols but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL