# How to strore a non english string to mysql database from java application

Tags: java, mysql, database

My question is about related to MySQL database.

Can any one help me to store a non English string from java application to MySQL database?

I tried in several ways. I changed the collisions of the database columns too. But when passed a non English string to the MySQL database, it shows a "???" mark in the table. Why is this happening?

When passed a English string, that is working fine. But when sending a non English string from the java application, that stores that non English string as a "?" mark on the database.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share the java code.and also the `show create table [table]` statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275661/984823 to communicate to the database in UTF-8 (Unicode). And the database / table / column must be defined for containing UTF8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly

Answer (score 0):

yu need t change table collection to utf8_genereal_ci or any of this utf8 collection, also in columt data type to string r long string

Comment: I have already used the collasions that you have mentioned. But I used varchar as the datatype of the column. So, will datatype "varchar" affect ?

Comment: i ve never used as varchar but as string and longstring and spanish character are welcome like this ñ or this á

Comment: Ok. I will try and will let you know the progress. Btw, thanks a lot for your big help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use UTF8 or UTF8MB4 as character set of the MySQL and chactersetEncoding as utf8 in case you are using JDBC connection from Java Application.

Comment: Hi, I tried with most of the collasions like above mentioned. But no luck. :(

Comment: Have you tried charactersetEncoding in JDBC connection?

Comment: Can you please show me how to set chactersetEncoding as utf8 ? Please. It would be big help for me.