# arabic data problem when it inserts from the java application (mysql , javafx)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I have a problem when I enter data from the application to mysql database, it appears in the form of "????" However, when I enter data via "phpmyadmin" the data appears normally
well the problem is when i enter data via application ,
 not related with database
any way i tried to change the encode of database and the table and the fields inside the tables

here the insert query in my application

```
 public static void dbConnect() {
        try{
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        connector = DriverManager.getConnection(DATA_BASE_BATH, "root", "");
        insert = connector.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO students VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

        }
public static void insert(int id , String name , String special , double gpa){
        dbConnect();
        try{
        insert.setInt(1, id);
        insert.setString(2, name);
        insert.setString(3,special);
        insert.setDouble(4,gpa);
        insert.execute();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

here the image to understand the problem

[image: database image]
-the first row is the data entry from the application
-and the second row is the data entry manually from the phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application isn't properly handling the data.

You need to set the charset during the connection to the MySQL server.

[Perhaps by running the command](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/Garbled_data#preventing) `SET NAMES 'UTF8';` as part of your connection script.

[This answer states that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275661/2385479) you can even make it part the JDBC connection string in `DATA_BASE_BATH` when referenced in your getConnection() function call, [as does this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042646/2385479).