# Character coding between mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql

I have an error in printing special characters in Java.

The system reads a product name from a mysql database, and checking the database from the command line, the data displays the Registered Symbol ® correctly.

A java program then runs a database read to get information of orders to print out as a PDF, but when the print is produced the ® symbol becomes 'fi'.

Is there a way of retaining the myself character coding when handling in Java?

Comment: There is maybe an encoding problem. Does encoding properties set when connecting to MySQL? Try to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275661/2530910. Also, could you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Before printing to PDF, you can replace the special characters with the unicode characters as below.

```
public static String specialCharactersConversion( String charString ) {          
     if( isNotEmpty( charString ) ){
          charString = charString.replaceAll(  "\\(R\\)", "\u00AE" );
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

So, what you can do before converting your text to PDF, you can convert special characters or entire text to Unicode sequences. The answer is copied with modifications from this question: [Convert International String to \u Codes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java/53946044#53946044)


The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)